# Prevent automatic Google shorten URL visit

Tags: php, google-url-shortener

When a user request a password reset, we send an email with a reset link shortened by Google URL Shortener.

Problem is, the link is being visited before / without the user clicking it.  How can I prevent this?

```
// Google Shorten URL code.
$googer = new GoogleURLAPI($key);
$short_url = $googer->shorten($short_url);
return $short_url;`
```

Comment: Show your code for better understanding of your problem..

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Google will fetch the link to get information (such as the title) from it as part of the shortening service.

Just send a regular link like everyone else. You don't need it to be pasted into Twitter (where there is a message length limit) or posted on a billboard (where people have to type it).

Comment: in this case http referee doesn't show google bot but just a normal referer

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and actually checking the HTTP referee doesn't help as in this case it doesn't display GoogleBot. I guess the machine checking the URL is really not the google bot used for crawling.
The only way i found to detect that it is google which is visiting the URL is by checking the IP address hostname and looking for google name in it.

Such as executing `host 66.249.88.231` in a shell.

Comment: is correct, google does not consistently set any headers that would allow you to detect the bot from the request, so you would need to do a reverse DNS lookup, which on a unix host `host IP_ADDRESS` will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

If you really need this solution, you could try to detect the Google Bot visiting your reset page.
It should send a specific user agent.